# ¿Como quitar las propiedades css añadidas con jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

como puedo quitar las propiedades que se cambian del css con jquery,
este es mi codigo:

```
$("#box_archivos").click(function(){
     $("#box_datos").css({'height':'270px'});
     $("#box_archivos").css({'height':'90%'});
     $("#box_textarea").css({'display':'none'});
   });
```

lo que yo quiero es cuando doi click en #box_datos las css añadidas con jquery que se quiten y vuelva al css normal.
Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo mismo pasándole como valor un `String` vacio `""`. De este modo elimina el estilo que se le añade `inline` y vuelve a coger el `computed-style`

```
$("#box_datos").css({'height':''});
```

> Establecer el valor de una propiedad de estilo en una cadena vacía, p. Ej. $ ("#mydiv") .css ("color", ""): elimina esa propiedad de un elemento si ya se ha aplicado directamente.

Traducido de [.css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

---

**Snippet ejemplo:**

```js
$("#box_archivos").click(function(){
  $("#box_datos").css({'height':'270px'});
  $("#box_archivos").css({'height':'90%'});
  $("#box_textarea").css({'display':'none'});
});

$("#remove_css").click(function(){
  $("#box_datos").css({'height':''});
  $("#box_archivos").css({'height':''});
  $("#box_textarea").css({'display':''});
});
```

```css
.item {
  display:block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="box_archivos">ADD CSS</button>
<div id="box_datos" class="item"></div>
<div id="box_archivos" class="item"></div>
<div id="box_textarea" class="item"></div>
<button id="remove_css">REMOVE CSS</button>
```

Comment: gracias, por el aporte muy bueno....